# MSIX package for WinForms

Tags: winforms, package, msix

Hi i need your help understanding an incident that occurred with me, i have published on MS store an winform app that i have added to it MSIX package, the app was published successfully on MS Store but Microsoft have added information: THIS APP USES ALL SYSTEM RESOURCES and a link permission description that explaines what that means, it basically telling that this app have full controll of your device, that is the concern i am having because it will scare any potential users from installing this app on their device. The app is not using any read/write or collecting users location or sending/getting info through the internet, all it does is embeding the input code that the user has added to a text field then takes that code inside json snippet format inside the same text field then the user can copy the generated json snippet for the use in VS code user snippet usage. Is there any other ways to avoid when published to MS store an winform package inside MSIX MS  writing next to the published app the message: USES ALL SYSTEM RESOURCES?

I have Tried solving it by creating UWP but the layoud is giving me Headache, i managed creating similar app but the look is not how i want to be, example when someone changes the window size all the elements goes out of position, some disappears and time consumption working with xaml.

Comment: It's not an error, it means, in a kind of contorted, supposedly User-Friendly manner, that the App runs in Full Trust (not exactly that *it has full control of ones device* :) -- If you have better terms to explain that to the end user, do post your suggestion to the marketplace guys